# Google Docs API 3.0 - Downloading a document

Tags: java, google-docs-api

I am writing Google Docs to my local app document downloader.

In Google Docs API page:

http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#DownloadingDrawings

They say that:

> Important: We highly recommend using the link provided by an entry's content link and not constructing this URL manually.

I have explored all Entry attributes, but I really can't find the appropriate link attribute. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MediaContent mc = (MediaContent) entry.getContent();
String UrlForDownload = mc.getUri();
```

Thats it!

tada!